# writing to file: the difference between stream and writer

Tags: java, file, stream, writer

Hi I have a bit of confusion about the stream to use to write in a text file

I had seen some example:

one use the PrintWriter stream

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fname)));

out.println(/*something to write*/);

out.close();
```

this instead use:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(fname));

out.println(/*something to write*/)
```

but which is the difference?both write in a file with the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PrintWriter` is new as of Java 1.1; it is more capable than the `PrintStream` class. You should use `PrintWriter` instead of `PrintStream` because it uses the default encoding scheme to convert characters to bytes for an underlying `OutputStream`. The constructors for `PrintStream` are deprecated in Java 1.1. In fact, the whole class probably would have been deprecated, except that it would have generated a lot of compilation warnings for code that uses `System.out` and `System.err`.

Answer (score 1):

`PrintWriter` is for writing text, whereas `PrintStream` is for writing data - raw bytes. `PrintWriter` may change the encoding of the bytes to make handling text easier, so it might corrupt your data.

Comment: Which is the best method to write in a text file without encouring in error?

Comment: `PrintWriter` should write text just fine.

Comment: Just use `PrintWriter`. In Java 5, there is even a constructor `PrintWriter(String filename)` for your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

`PrintWriter` extends the class `Writer`, a class thinked to write characters, while `PrintStream` implements `OutputStream`, an interface for more generic outputs.